# Integration: $\int\frac{dx}{1+(\sin(x))^4}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

What is the answer to this integration?

$$\int\frac{dx}{1+(\sin(x))^4}$$

how to solve in. it was asked in btec placement of a collage.

Comment: do you mean $$\int\frac{dx}{1+(\sin(x))^4}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write $$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$ with $$t=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
for your control, this is the result:
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-i} \tan (x)\right)}{2 \sqrt{1-i}}+\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+i} \tan
   (x)\right)}{2 \sqrt{1+i}}+C$$

Comment: I have tried this but it does't work.

Comment: why it doesn't work?

Comment: I think one can get an answer without complex numbers. $\sin^2x=\dfrac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$

Comment: please show the full precess

Comment: can we go with an substitution of algebra.